# What are the differences between "enterprise" and "home" Linux distributions?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, linux-distributions

Simply as the title says, what are the main differences between these two kind of distributions?

Being Linux basically suited to be tailored to each own preferences and fully customizable in every aspect, what marks the border between these two worlds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a general comparison between the two:

### Enterprise distributions

- Usually developed by open-source companies such as Red Hat and SUSE
- Targeted for commercial markets such as businesses and academia
- Usually available through subscription plans, however some may be
  free such as CentOS
- Offer a variety of editions for server, desktop, workstation, and management platforms
- Slower release cycle (24-36 months) to maintain stable releases
- Offer technical support

Notable enterprise linux distributions: Red Hat Enterprise Linux, SUSE Linux Enterprise, Oracle Linux, CentOS

### Home/Personal distributions

- Community developed, although some are also developed by open-source
  companies such as Canonical's Ubuntu
- Targeted to consumers/individuals
- Nearly always freely available
- Usually only develop desktop and server editions
- Faster release cycle (usually every 6 months) to add more features
  and fix issues, however some distros are based on a rolling release
  cycle which constantly provide updates instead of releasing major
  version upgrades

Notable personal distributions: Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Fedora, openSUSE, Debian, Arch Linux